# Multiple belongsTo() associations in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3.x.
My question is : Is it possible to have many belongsTo() associations with the same foreign key ?

Here's my issue :
I have three fields in my table which are using the same foreign key.

In the Model Table, I used belongsTo() association this way :

```
$this->belongsTo('Pilotes', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'pilote',
    'propertyName' => 'pilote_user'
]);

$this->belongsTo('Verificateurs', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'no_user',
    'propertyName' => 'verificateur_user'
]);

$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'no_user',
    'propertyName' => 'user'
]);
```

But when I debug my entity, the two first fields only contain the foreign key, and the last one is fine.

The query :

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $demande = $this->Demandes->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ]);
    $this->set('demande', $demande);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['demande']);
}
```

Here is the output of debug() :

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Demande) {
'new' => false,
'accessible' => [
    'pilote' => true,
    'verificateur' => true,
    'pilote_user' => true,
    'verificateur_user' => true,
    'user' => true,
],
'properties' => [
    'no_demande' => (int) 4,
    'pilote' => (int) 3,
    'verificateur' => (int) 2,
    'no_user' => (int) 1,
    'user' => object(App\Model\Entity\User) {
        /* Details of the user */
    },
],
'dirty' => [],
'original' => [],
'virtual' => [],
'errors' => [],
'repository' => 'Demandes'
}
```

If I comment my last belongsTo(), the second field is fine , but not the first one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What query generates this result?

Comment: I added the query to my post

Comment: You need to contain the other associations `'contain' => ['Users', 'Verificateurs', 'Pilotes']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the name in the first argument:

```
$this->belongsTo('Pilotes', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'pilote',
    'propertyName' => 'pilote_user'
]);

$this->belongsTo('Verificateurs', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'verificateur',
    'propertyName' => 'verificateur_user'
]);

$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'no_user',
    'propertyName' => 'user'
]);
```

Note that as you chose to use `pilote` and `verificateur` as column names in your schema, you need to change the value of `propertyName`. This is because Cake will create a property in your entities with that name and it will collide with the properties in your table.

That is the reason I had to choose `pilote_user` as a property name for your entity, for example.

When querying you data you will need to add `'contain' => ['Users', 'Verificateurs', 'Pilotes']` to the finder options

Comment: I'm still getting only the foreign key with your code. The foreign key is the same field for my three associations, only the value is changing

Comment: It cannot be the same foreign key for all three belongsTo associations, for reasons that I hope are obvious :)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something in the Cookbook, but why can't I have the same foreign key for different attributes ? **belongsTo()** represents an association 1-n, doesn't it ?

Comment: Wouldn't that be hasMany? 1 record in the table has n in the other, that is hasMany to me. A belongsTo association is n - 1

Comment: I hosted a screenshot of my tables [here](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1430834285.jpg). `no_user` is the foreign key of `pilote`, `verificateur` and `no_user`, so it should be **belongsTo()**, right ? On the other side, I have `hasMany()` in my table `Users`. Am I completely wrong ?

Comment: Yeah, you can only have one association per foreignKey. One big exception would be adding extra conditions to the association to identify the user with the same foreignKey + a discriminating condition

Comment: What are the reasons of this constraint ? I mean, why can we set the same foreign key for multiple fields in MySQL, and not using it with CakePHP ?

Comment: Let me try to understand something first, since all those associations will have the same foreign key, do you actually expect having different values for each of the associations?

Comment: Oh, by looking again at your schema I see that you actually have different foreign keys!!! the foreign keys are `pilote`, `verificateur` and `no_user`.. So you actually have different foreign keys for each of the associations you want to create

Comment: Yes, I think I was not clear enough. `no_user` in `Users` is the reference key, and in `Demandes`, `pilote`, `verificateur` and `no_user` can have different values

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. I got the same issue, except the fact that I now got an error  Demandes is not associated with Users` if I comment my last association. I think it's caused by the lack of the entities `Pilotes` and `Verificateurs`. So I tried to keep `Users` for the first argument, and I got the result in the new property, but still only one.

Comment: Update your question with the associations as you have them now